# how to search for a directory from the terminal in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-12.04

I am using Ubuntu and I want to search for a specific Directory called "sdk".

All that I know is, that "sdk" Directory is located somewhere under /user Directory

how can I search for "sdk" Directory from the terminal?

I tried the following `find / -name example docs -type d`

but it says no such file or Directory.

Comment: try ```locate sdk```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

you can search for directory by using `find` with flag `-name`

you should use

```
find /user -name "sdk" -type d
```

meaning find directories named sdk in or below the directory /user

or if you want to be case-insensitive

```
find /user -iname "sdk" -type d
```

Comment: For perf reasons put the `-type d` before the name check as it's cheaper to check if a node is a directory. The order matters with `find`

Answer (score 14):

Please try the below command.

```
locate foldername | grep /foldername$
```

Comment: `locate -r` accepts a regex so no need to grep. Besides, linux/unix has directories, not folders

Comment: This solution worked a lot better for me than the one with all the votes because the other solution seemed to return every directory. Using just 
```locate directory```
like the other comment says has the problem of returning all sub directories that have it in the path.